# Is there a way to unpack jar using maven plugin to my project folder and get them as java files

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-2, maven-plugin

Is there a way to unpack jar using maven plugin to my project folder and get them as java files I tried using maven dependency plugin to unpack the jar to my project folder location and it was giving class files. Is there a way to get them as java files? If not is there any other way to get java files from a maven jar to my project folder?

Comment: What end result do you want to achieve? Do you want this to happen as part of your build, or is this a one-off exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Files are compiled so you cannot immediately do what you want.

Some Maven artifacts have sources attached, and if you download those, you can get the original source back.

Comment: Note: if you don’t need to change anything in then class files are fine